# jQuery: Check if an element with the same attribute exists more than once

Tags: jquery, loops, attributes, removechild

I would like to check if an element with the same data attribute exists more than once in a jQuery each loop and if exists more than once remove it and keep only one element with this data attribute.

I tried this code but doesnt seems to work,

HTML:

```
<div class="list" data-productid="2"></div> // KEEP THIS ONE

<div class="list" data-productid="3"></div>

<div class="list" data-productid="2"></div> // REMOVE THIS ONE

<div class="list" data-productid="2"></div> // REMOVE THIS ONE
```

My approach in jQuery:

```
$('.list').each(function(){

if ( $(this).attr(data-productid).length > 0 ) {

$(this).remove();


}

});
```

Any ideas guys,

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of each one either in array or object. Then as duplicates are found they can be removed

```
var productIds={};
$('.list').each(function(){
    var prodId = $(this).attr('data-productid');
    if(productIds[prodId]){
       $(this).remove();
    }else{
       productIds[prodId] = true;
    }
});
```

You could search the DOM for each one but that is far more expensive especially if you have a big list

Answer (score 2):

You could remove any dupe which isn't the first one:

```
$('.list').each(function(){
   $('[data-productid='+$(this).data('productid')+']:not(:first)').remove();
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: might be considered best by short code...but far more expensive...especially on a big list

Answer (score 0):

do it like this. refere the working demo

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

<body>

<div class="list" data-productid="2">one</div> 

<div class="list" data-productid="3">two</div>

<div class="list" data-productid="2">one</div> 

<div class="list" data-productid="2">one</div> 



<script type="text/javascript">

var isin = [];
$('div.list').each(function(){
 var data_product = $(this).attr('data-productid');
 if(isin[data_product])
 {
  $(this).remove();
 }
 else
 {
  isin[data_product] = true;
 }
 
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```